# PHP outputting inconsistent values from same array

Tags: php

In phpmyadmin and in the print_r of the entire array the value for template_id is 3, but when I print the value directly I get 31?

Any inights as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

When I print_r from $data['resume'] I get:

> Array ( [profile_id] => 38 [name] => Amy P. Cherwim [occupation] =>
>   Administrative Assistant [tagline] => Administrative Assistant [phone]
>   => 444-222-4339 [fax] => [email] => alcherwin@email.com [website] => [address] => 336 W. Chugalug Way Sentinel, WY  33666 [user_id] => 1
>   [title] => Amy's Profile [date_add] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [date_mod]
>   => 2012-03-04 10:53:40 [resume_id] => 316 [vanity_name] => Copy of Sample of Template 3 [template_id] => 3 [scale] => 1 ) 1

When I print_r from $data['resume']['template_id'] I get: 31

Comment: Don't you see the `1` also at the end of your `print_r` output? You don't need to use `echo` with `print_r`, it's like saying `echo TRUE;`.

Comment: `echo $data['resume']['template_id'];` will give you `3`. Print_r adds 1 at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print_r` returns true as well as echoing (hence 3 for the value, 1 for true). To have it just return the value, use `print_r($var, true)`.

Comment: I always use print_r to view arrays and I guess I just never realized it treats string differently. Thx so much.

Comment: It doesn't treat strings differently. See the 1 on the end of your array print? ;)